# How to get the number of files/resources read by MultiResourceItemReader i.e. length of Resource[]?

Tags: spring-batch

I have a folder where files are downloaded from an upstream source. Some files may have multiple records, some may have 1 record. These are to be processed using **Spring Batch** (version **3.0.6**)

I need to get the count of files i.e. length of the Resource[] in MultiResourceItemReader.

```
<bean id="myreader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader" scope="step">        
        <beans:property name="resources" value="file:#{'${base.path}'+'/'+'sourceX'+'/'+'received/*.xml'}" />
        <beans:property name="delegate" ref="customMultiFileReader" />
</bean>
```

Here *customMultiFileReader* bean is an implementation of *ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream*. It provides handle to current resource. But I need to get the Resource[] (array) to get the count of files in the folder.

How to do this?

Comment: Why would the delegate be aware of all the resources (and/or their count)? IMO, your delegate should not contain `Multi` in its name because It's sole responsibility is to handle a single resource. Does this make sense?

Comment: Well, I agree to the naming convention point. 
But I wanted to know if there is way to get the resource count other than using a counter variable.

Comment: The naming convention is a detail. The point is about the design of the delegate which should only be aware of the resource at hand while the `MultiResourceItemReader` is responsible of handling all the resources. Anyway, to answer your precise question, you can add a `Resource[]` field + a setter in your `customMultiFileReader` and pass the same resources object to both the `customMultiFileReader` and `MultiResourceItemReader`. Something like: `<bean id="customMultiFileReader" class=".."><property name="resources" value="same resources reference passed to MultiResourceItemReader"/></bean>`